# How do quantum probabilities transform under Lorentz transformations?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, reference-frames, probability

I think I get how scattering probabilities transform under Lorentz transforms. Once the interaction phase is over, the final probabilities become time independent. Hence, every observer could describe the final state using the same probabilities.

But I don't understand how **time-dependent** probabilities would transform under a change of frame. Suppose there's a quantum system in a box whose probabilistic state at time $t$ is described by some wavefunction/wavefunctional $\psi (t)$. How would a moving observer describe the probabilistic state of the same system? I think the concept of "probability at a time" gets screwed up because of different planes of simultaneties for the two observers.

Comment: Does this help? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/588420/

Comment: @Mauricio No, I already assume. second quantisation in this post, which is why I said "wavefunctional at time $t$"

Comment: What do you need this for? How does it work classically: consider a classical trajectory $x(t)$ - how does that behave? Why would the quantum trajectory in Hilbert space behave differently?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I think it gets screwed up because probabilities are defined at a time.  Let's take $\psi (t_0)$ at time $t_0$ of some frame $A$. In frame $A$, some proper time $t_1$ of frame $B$ is simultaneous with $t_0$. But in frame $B$, some other time $t_2$ is simultaneous with $t_0$. So do you map the probability $\psi (t_0)$ to $t_1$ or to $t_2$ in B's frame?

Comment: Again: How is this different from what happens with a classical trajectory $x(t)$?

Comment: @ACuriousMind But we have a formula to use on classical trajectories or even classical fields. The same formula can't be used on wavefunctionals because wavefunctionals are probability distributions on 3D field configurations. The formula is for 4D field configurations.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Please give me a formula or an algorithm to use on time dependent wavefunctionals.

Comment: You might be interested in this classic that discusses the Lorentz transformation for photons https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0508202

Comment: You might be interested in the book *Local Quantum Measurement and Relativity. Christian Beck. Springer.*.

Answer (score 2):

There is no universal answer here. Transformation formulas depend on the way you describe (enumerate) system states: it can be done in invariant and non-invariant way, consistent with system symmetry or not. So the only answer to your question is: they transform *somehow, as some [representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_of_a_Lie_group) of Lorentz group*.

###### ADDENDUM

In general case we have some Hilbert space $\mathcal H$. We can imagine a time dependent state as a moving point in the $\mathcal T \times \mathcal H$ fiber space, where $\mathcal T$ is the time axe. To put this theory into special relativity context, some Lorentz group representation $L: \mathcal T \times \mathcal H \to \mathcal T \times \mathcal H$ should be defined.

Comment: This works for time independent states. Like in scattering experiments, because we take the $t\rightarrow \infty$ limit, the states in the asymptotic past and future transform according to the representations of Lorentz group. But more generally, you can have a system of elementary particles packed in an extremely tiny box such that their interaction phase is never over. Now we must use a time dependent wavefunctional to describe the state of this system at time $t$. How would this quantity transform under a change of frame?

Comment: @RyderRude, I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Wavefunctions are not compatible with Special Relativity where the number of particles can be changed over the course of an experiment, perhaps what you mean then is something like the electron field? If so the problem is just not there since all formulations of QFT are manifestly Lorentz invariant (just look at their lagrangians), meaning that observables like squared scattering amplitudes (which are the only thing you can observe about a system) are automatically Lorentz Invariant and thus all observers agree on their value.

Comment: Yes, I know the $S$ matrix probabilities are invariant if we integrate over the entire spacetime in the Dyson series. But I want to understand more general situations than scattering experiments. More generally, if we don't take the $x,y,z,t \rightarrow \infty$ limits, the state of a QFT system can be described by a time dependent probability wavefunctional $\psi [\phi, t]$. I want to understand how this quantity transforms as this refers to more general situations than scattering experiments.

Comment: I mean squared scattering amplitudes, aka squares of sums of Feynman diagrams, those (un-integrated) objects are Lorentz Invariant. There is nothing more general than an scattering experiment... all one can do in the universe is send probes to systems and measure what comes out to form a "picture" of what the system is and its properties. When you think of a system as a thing which you can "see" that already assumes you are collecting light coming from it, light which scattered with the system.

Comment: @DiógenesFigueroa Can you substantiate the remark "there is nothing more general than a scattering experiment"? It seems to me that the limit $t \to \infty$, considering the fact that we are only able to do experiments at finite times, can only ever lead to approximate results. Those results may, with a detector sufficiently far from the scattering center, be such a good approximation to an exact theory that the experiment cannot detect the difference. However it is still clear that the limit $t \to \infty$ is but an approximation.

Comment: In this sense, it seems to me that rather than "there is nothing more general than a scattering experiment", it seems to be the case that "there is no real experiment which is a perfect scattering experiment, and the degree of deviation depends on the exact setup". It therefore seems clear to me that there is a usefulness in the discussion of finite-time effects.

Comment: I guess what you mean is that in QFT one uses an approximation of infinitely localized packages in momentum space which have been evolving for infinite time, in that sense I do agree with you that a more realistic picture would be a good idea. People have tried this with thigs like using coherent states instead of momentum eigenstates, however I'm not too familiar with that literature.

Comment: @DiógenesFigueroa Yes, the fact that these states are modeled to evolve for infinite time after the interaction event is an approximation, and due to this approximation the scattering framework cannot necessarily be applied to finite-time phenomena without some specific justification. As for the localization in momentum space I have seen some treatments of this which model the states as finite-width wave packets in momentum space, and they seem to work out well so that is less of a concern.

Answer (score 1):

For the free QFT, the boost of a time dependent solution of the Schrodinger eqn is given by :

$$|p_1, p_2...\rangle e^{-i\omega _{p_1} t -i \omega _{p_2} t....}\rightarrow |\Lambda p_1 , \Lambda p_2...\rangle e^{-i \omega _{\Lambda p_1 } t - i \omega _{\Lambda p_2}t.....}$$

The boosted basis vector also obeys the Schrodinger equation.

This can be used to boost any time dependent solution of the Schrodinger equation in the Fock space. The boost of a time-dependent wavefunctional $\psi [\phi]$ can be found out by a change of basis to the Fock space.

For the interacting theory, the boost transformation generally depends on the Hamiltonian, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/785467/does-the-generator-of-boosts-depend-on-the-hamiltonian).