# Is the collapse of the wavefunction relativistic?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, special-relativity, measurement-problem, wavefunction-collapse

If a stationary observer, 'A', observes the collapse of a wavefunction, does an observer, 'B', traveling at relativistic speed observe a different collapse of the same wavefunction?
What do all the interpretations says about this topic?

Comment: Everyone will agree about the measurement outcome. In most interpretations, there is no "physical collapse". And it has never been seen experimentally...

Comment: You can calculate the wavefunction before and after the collapse in each reference frame. There is no ambiguity.

Comment: Note also that in relativity we prefer to use fields and not wavefunctions.

Comment: @Mauricio I wouldn't say so without further caveats (and one has to be very precise here). There are problems with the description of relativistic measurements, even in (relativistic) QFT. See e.g. *Quantum information and relativity theory. Peres and Treno. III B*. Or *Quantum Information in Relativity: The Challenge of QFT Measurements. Anastopoulos and Savvidou. Section 3.1* and the references therein.

Comment: This may help - [Does the collapse of the wave function happen immediately everywhere?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/622155/37364)

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/749475/is-collapse-of-wavefunction-actually-relative/749500#749500

Comment: @TobiasFünke the only problem I can see with that is when you have entangled states, but that is not the question here...

Comment: This could also help: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/588420/lorentz-transformation-of-wavefunction#:~:text=Consider%20two%20frames%20S%20and,%CF%88%E2%80%B2(x%E2%80%B2).

Comment: Thank you everyone

Comment: Can the collapse be "observed"?